# Não consigo chamar o CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Quando utilizo o @Html.EditorFor e chamo o css, não vem no input quando executo, mesmo tirando o new { htmlAttributes }

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario.MATRICULA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control bg-light border-bottom col-md-3" } })
```

Input quando executado:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo é obrigatório" id="Usuario_MATRICULA" name="Usuario.MATRICULA" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas solucionam seu problema? Precisa de mais algum detalhe?

Answer (score 0):

mais como você esta chamando o css?

o código esta na pagina ou esta chamando um arquivo css?

era mais pratico chamar no head

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

ou

```
<style>

</style>
```

vendo aqui, acho que tem que setar as classes corretamente, tenta assim:

Modelo:

```
public class User_mat
{
    public int User_matId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string User_matName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool isNewlyEnrolled { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}


@model User_mat

@Html.TextBox("User_mat", null, new { @class = "form-control bg-light border-bottom col-md-3" }) 

<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  id="User_mat" name="User_mat"  value="" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo é obrigatório">
```

Aqui explica detalhadamente: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-textbox-textboxfor

Comment: O codigo na view está assim: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario.MATRICULA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control bg-light border-bottom col-md-3" } })

Comment: Mas quando dou F12 na página ele me retorna assim: <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo é obrigatório" id="Usuario_MATRICULA" name="Usuario.MATRICULA" type="text" value="">

Comment: Não chama o CSS que declaro no @Html.EditorFor

Answer (score 0):

Troque o `EditorFor` para `TextBoxFor` e o terceiro parâmetro precisa ser um objeto direto com os atributos HTML, não com essa propriedade `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Usuario.MATRICULA, 
                 new { @class = "form-control bg-light border-bottom col-md-3" } )
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/osawzi)